# Asymptotic Question

Tags: asymptotics

Hi how do I find the asymptotic bound for the recurrence **T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + T(n/8) + n?**

Can I use master theorem or Substitution method only?
If so, I need some help for substitution method. My attempt is as below:

Sub T(n/2) into T(n/2) + j(n) = T(n/(2^2) + j(n/2)
T(n) = T(n/(2^2) + j(n/2) + j(n)

Sub T(n/2^2) into T(n/2) + j(n) = T(n/(2^3) + j(n/2^3) 
T(n) = T(n/(2^3) + j(n/2^3) + j(n)
     = T(n/2^i) + (n/2^k)

ok then I'm not sure what to do from here...

Comment: Use the Akra-Bazzi theorem. You can also prove that $T(n)=O(n)$ by induction.

Comment: The master theorem only applies to recurrences of the form $T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n)$, which is not what you have here.

Comment: See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/83650/68251).